# Java - code is executing in 2 switch cases

Tags: java

I'm debugging my application in IntelliJ and it seems like my code is going into 2 switch statements instead of 1.

My code looks like this:

```
final String CASE_1 = "case_1";
final String CASE_2 = "case_2";

switch(CASE): {
   CASE_1: {
      // do something
   }

   CASE 2: {
     // do something
   }
}
```

My application executes the code that's in both cases.

Is there any reason why the code would go into both cases?
(I'm intentionally not pasting my actual code since it's impossible to reproduce locally without creating the whole structure of the project)

Comment: you need to add the break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a break after each case, otherwise it forwards to the next case.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String CASE_1 = "case_1";
        final String CASE_2 = "case_2";

        String CASE = "case_1";

        switch(CASE){
            case CASE_1:{
                System.out.println("Case 1 Found");
                break; //Put a break here if you don't want the code to execute for the next case as well.
            }
            case CASE_2:{
                System.out.println("Case 2 Found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why would it forward to the next case if it doesn't equal to `CASE`? Or maybe i need to learn the fundamentals of `switch` :D

Comment: If it's not equal to the first case, then it will never enter the first case. Right ? So in that case, it shouldn't automatically forward to the second case either, and since you didn't show a "default" case for your switch, it should simply exit that switch's scope. 
But if it matches the first case, or somehow the case wasn't written properly, and for that it enters the first case, without presence of a break, it'll keep going to the next case. That's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

Because you dont end the case

```
   public void runTest(String CASE) {
        switch (CASE) {
            case CASE_1:
                // code block
                break;
            case CASE_2:
                // code block
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```